# How to pack a Plotly-Dash application with pyinstaller into a single exe file for windows?

Tags: windows, pyinstaller, plotly-dash

I have a script that runs a plotly-dash dashboard. When I pack it with

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```

and run the generated .exe file, I get the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI161122\\dash_html_components\\package-info.json'
[5968] Failed to execute script
```

What is going on here exactly and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Sören, have you managed to find a solution to the problem you've had last year? I'm encountering the exact same error as you when i compile to `--onefile`

Comment: Hi etjk, I added what I think was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution was to add that component to `datas` list in the specfile.

```
...
datas=[('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_html_components', '.\\dash_html_components'), ...] 
...
```

Though I am not sure. I stopped using the `--onefile` option as it took too long to start the app. Instead, I went on using `--onedir`.

#### Full specfile:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['..\\scripts\\Mint.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\username\\workspace\\ms-mint'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_html_components', '.\\dash_html_components'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_table', '.\\dash_table'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_core_components', '.\\dash_core_components'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_renderer', '.\\dash_renderer'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_bootstrap_components', '.\\dash_bootstrap_components'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_html_components', '.\\dash_html_components'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\dash_extensions', '.\\dash_extensions'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly', '.\\plotly'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\pyopenms\\share', '.\\pyopenms\\share'),
                    ('C:\\Users\\username\\anaconda3\\envs\\ms-mint\\lib\\site-packages\\pymzml', '.\\pymzml'),

                    ],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn'],  
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Mint',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Mint')
```